# Why this is called semi norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

How to prove the following is semi-norm $$[u]_{s,p}=\Bigg(\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+sp}}dxdy\Bigg)^{1/p}$$ where $\Omega$ open set in $\mathbb R^n$, $1\leq p<\infty$, $0<s<1$.

As a semi-norm satisfying triangle inequality and homogeneous. I am facing problem in triangle inequality.

Comment: Isn´t there something missing in Your definition of $[.]_{s,p}$, something like $[]_{s,p}=(...)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and shouldn´t $\Omega$ be bounded?

Comment: Yes...but $\Omega$ be an open set. In the definition of fractional Sobolev space, it is called Gagliardo semi-norm but it does not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: So why it's called semi-norm?

Comment: You´re right: It suffices to assume $\Omega$ open. For the triangle inequality: What makes You think it´s violated. I think I found a proof that i will post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously $[.]_{s,p}$ is homogeneous. Define for $u:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the function $\phi_u:\Omega\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by:
$$\phi_u(x,y)=\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\frac{n}{p}+s}}.$$
Then $||\phi_u||_{L^p(\Omega\times\Omega)}=[u]_{s,p}$.By the triangle inequality on $\mathbb{R}$

$$\phi_{u+v}(x,y)=\frac{|(u+v)(x)-(u+v)(y)|}{|x-y|^{\frac{n}{p}+s}}\leq \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\frac{n}{p}+s}}+\frac{|v(x)-v(y)|}{|x-y|^{\frac{n}{p}+s}}$$
for all $x,y\in\Omega$ and thus
$$||\phi_{u+v}||_{L^p(\Omega\times\Omega)}\leq ||\phi_u+\phi_v||_{L^p(\Omega\times\Omega)}\leq||\phi_u||_{L^p(\Omega\times\Omega)}+||\phi_v||_{L^p(\Omega\times\Omega)}$$, by the Minkowski-inequality and that yields
$$[u+v]_{s,p}\leq[u]_{s,p}+[v]_{s,p}$$
which makes the Gagliardo semi-norm a real semi-norm but no norm since all constant functions have Gagliardo semi norm zero.

Comment: I recommend http://math.sns.it/media/doc/paper/1385/dpv-revised-preprint.pdf , it seems like they don´t proof the triangle inequality for the Gagliardo semi-norm there though.

Comment: You´re welcome!

Comment: The above link does not work anymore, the paper can be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0007449711001254)